# Basic statistical analysis steps

Tags: r, anova, pairwise, posthoc

I would like to know if my codes make sense. A colleague of mine sent them it to me and I have been using them but I have the feeling some things are not correct.
In the next codes, I attempted to analyse Shapiro and Levene tests to know if could perform an ANOVA or if I had to use a non-parametric test (like Kruskal-Wallis).
The data belongs to a subset of a column named `Sediment_type`, where I want to analyse just the data belonging to the "sandy" sediment. Hence why I made the object `subset_sandy`. The excel file is named "Morphology_Lab_T1_D57_AGB" and the factor I want to statistically combine with the `subset_sandy` is a column called `Wave_type`.

**First step)** Find if there is normality (Shapiro) and homogeneity (Levene) among the data:

```
subset_sandy \<- subset(Morphology_Lab_T1_D57_AGB, Sediment_type == "Sandy")

subset_sandy$Wave_type \<- as.factor(subset_sandy$Wave_type)

AN_sandy \<- lm(Mean_L.\_leaf_length \~ Wave_type, data = subset_sandy)

AN_sandy

par(mfrow = c(2, 2))

plot(AN_sandy)

shapiro.test((AN_sandy$res)) # Normality (α \< 0.2477)

leveneTest(AN_sandy$res, subset_sandy$Wave_type) # Homogeneity (α \< 0.3243)
```

**Second step)** In this case, p-value was higher in both tests than alpha, so I proceeded to do a pairwise test (I guess equal to ANOVA, please correct me if I am wrong):

```
pairwise_result_sandy \<- pairwise.t.test(subset_sandy$Mean_L.\_leaf_length,

subset_sandy$Wave_type,

p.adjust.method = "bonferroni")

print("Pairwise comparisons for Sandy Sediment")

print(pairwise_result_sandy)
```

**Doubts:**

1. My doubts with regards these codes is the function `lm()` I have been using in the first step, since I realized it makes linear regression. However, my colleague has been doing this for long time.
2. Is `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` important for my analysis? I do not understand what it means.
3. I was told that `p.adjust.method` is not equivalent as "Post-hoc", but in my codes I add (`= "bonferroni"`) to this `p.adjust.method`. I would like to perform a Post-hoc too.

Comment: Hi @Alba Mayorga. Since this is really a question about aspects of the analysis, as opposed to a programming issue, you're best off asking this at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Regarding Doubt #2, however, I can clarify that it isn't directly important in terms of the statistical analysis. `par(mfrow = c(2,2)` applies a setting to create a 2x2 set of plots in a single image.